# Ruby on Rails .size not working

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, integer, size

In rails I am using an integer to represent a user's phone number.

When I get the output from `@user.phone_number` I get `=> 4088388579` which is 10 digits and the phone number that was entered.

When I do `@user.phone_number.size` I get `=> 8`

Why is this doing this?

FYI: I have a validation in the model that verifies that the length is 10 digits. `validates :phone_number, :length => {is: 10, :message => "A phone number needs to be 10 digits"}`

Comment: what is the output of `puts @user.phone_number.class` ?

Comment: @ArupRakshit Fixnum is what is being returned

Comment: Now do `@user.phone_number.to_s.size`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Ruby like in many languages an Integer (class `Fixnum`) is formed by 8 bytes in 64-bit machines (4 bytes in 32-bit ones). So the `.size` method returns the number of bytes that this number represents.

If your number were [big enough](http://patshaughnessy.net/2014/1/9/how-big-is-a-bignum), like a Long in other languages (class `Bignum`) it will be formed by 12 bytes (actually it depends of the machine architecture).

To check the length of characters as a literal, you can do: `your_number.to_s.size`.

For instance:

```
$ > 0.class
 # => Fixnum 
$ > 0.size 
 # => 8 

$ > 99999999999999999999.class
 # => Bignum 
$ > 99999999999999999999.size
 # => 12
```

Comment: How `4088388579.size` is giving OP `8`, but I am getting `4`. :(

Comment: @ArupRakshit: I guess you are in a 32-bit machine, that's why you are getting 4 bytes for a Fixnum.

Comment: Bignum actually expands to fit the number you give it :) `2123232123232123213232312323123231232312312323.size                                                                                                    
#=> 19`

Comment: Good appreciation @AaronCronin!